# Python:How to check if there is a datetime object in one dataframe that is related to another datetime?

Tags: python, date, datetime, dataframe

I need to calculate the job growth rate during the recession. I was given this dataframe:
[image]

And I also have a list of the dates:
[image]

Because I need the previous one year's value to calculate the growth rate, how can I extract the value from the dataframe that has a date: one year before my recession peak year(for example, 7/1937) and also in the same month(July)?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes. I changed the dates into datetime format and then I wanted to use .month and .year to check if there is "a previous year" exist in the dataframe, and that where I was stuck on. Should I use a for loop or something?

Answer (score 0):

This code calculates the sum of previous 1 year salary. You should modify it according to your need.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=100, freq='M')
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': rng, 'salary': 1, 'prev_1yr_tot_salary': 0})
df.prev_1yr_tot_salary = df.date.apply(lambda x: df.salary.loc[df.date.between(x - pd.DateOffset(years=1), x)].sum())
print df
```